# XML that passes isXML() but fails xmlParse() in ColdFusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I'm writing a test case for some ancient code that looks like this:

```
if (isXML(foo)) {
  try {
    bar = xmlParse(foo);
  }
  catch(any e) {
    // log error
  }
}
```

Blame reveals some backstory indicating we were seeing some XML strings for which `isXML` returned true, but for which `xmlParse` threw an exception of some sort.

What kind of string would produce this effect?

I've tried putting in a string I know is able to be parsed ok, then added an `&` in an element, but then `isXML` returns false. I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: *Some XML strings*  Show us.  *An exception of some sort*  Show us.  Until then, here's a SWAG:   `isXML()` is only checking for well-formedness, but `xmlParse()` is checking for validity against a schema.

Comment: The "some XML strings" part is precisely what I'm after.  Such strings and any logged exceptions are by now years long gone, sadly. The schema validity may well be what the issue was.  I will look into that. :)

Comment: @kjhughes I believe all CF function names are case-insensitive so "xmlParse()" and "XMLPARSE()" are the same thing.

Comment: I've encountered similar issues using isImage, isImageFile & isPDF.  The functions will evaluate to "true" and then throw an error when attempting to read the file.

Comment: `IsXml()`: _This function determines whether text is well-formed XML, that is, it conforms to all XML syntax and structuring rules. The string does not have to be a complete XML document. The function does not validate against a Document Type Definition (DTD) or XML Schema._  Maybe the xml is using some namespace but unable to find the definition. Example: https://trycf.com/gist/646fbaf11338a8681586aeb06a8b7288/acf11?theme=monokai

Comment: @Beginner Your trycf example is perfect and makes total sense.  If you add it as an answer I'll accept (and upvote). Obliged!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is the usage details of `IsXml()` from the [**DOCS**](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/isxml.html):

> This function determines whether text is well-formed XML, that is, it
>   conforms to all XML syntax and structuring rules. The string does not
>   have to be a complete XML document. The function does not validate
>   against a Document Type Definition (DTD) or XML Schema.

So, it might be possible that some namespace has been used but the definition was not found. i.e.,

```
<cfsavecontent variable="xml">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xyz:note>
      <xyz:to>Myself</xyz:to>
      <xyz:from>You</xyz:from>
      <xyz:heading>Reminder</xyz:heading>
      <xyz:body>Test</xyz:body>
    </xyz:note>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset xml = trim( xml )>

<!--- Try to parse --->
<cfset isXmlParsable = TRUE>
<cftry>
    <cfset XmlParse( xml )>

    <cfcatch>

        <!--- Will come here as xyz namespace is not defined --->
        <cfset isXmlParsable = FALSE>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<cfoutput>
    Is XML Valid: #IsXml( xml )#<br>
    Is XML Parsable: #isXmlParsable#
</cfoutput>
```

**Output:**

Is XML Valid: YES
Is XML Parsable: FALSE

Here is the [`GIST`](https://trycf.com/gist/4b79c632998545962282176591074aaf/acf11?theme=monokai).

Comment: It'd be more advantageous to make it reusable as a UDF.  https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/d716a2a30f8f0f0e603dd1990eef580b  I also noticed that isXMLDoc() may perform the same test (not entirely sure).

Comment: @JamesMoberg Yes, it would be better. `IsXmlDoc()` seems to be validating the XML as expected.